# mysql: 2 queries same result, but what method is fastest?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries that give me the same result set. I'm trying to choose which method is better and fastest...

QUERY #1

```
DESCRIBE SELECT *
FROM recording r
JOIN (
    SELECT r.work_id
    FROM recording r
    WHERE r.recording_id = 252
) t1 ON t1.work_id = r.work_id
```

QUERY #2

```
DESCRIBE SELECT *
FROM recording r
JOIN recording r2 ON r2.work_id = r.work_id
```

Is there an advantage choosing one method over the other ?
Thanks

Comment: First one should be slower because you are doing a JOIN plus you have a subquery

Comment: The queries are not equivalent as the latter is missing the where clause limiting to recording_id = 252, so either your example is missing a part or it's just a fluke that you get the same result.

Comment: Please post the results of the two [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) statements. They contain the answer you need.